# Terminology - exception

Tags: exception, error-handling, programming-languages, terminology

In programming, are exceptions always errors (divide by zero, access violation, ...)?

If not, can you provide examples of exceptions which are not errors?

Thanks.

Comment: Programming questions are offtopic here; migrating to [SO].

Comment: Exceptions are not always errors; one example would be Python's StopIteration exception which is risen when an iterator cannot produce any further value.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are often used to manage errors, they make error handling easier but they aren't always errors.

Every unordinary situation that require a separate code path could be a candidate for an exception.

Although the use of exceptions for control flow can be confusing (it depends largely on the language), they can be used to break out of a loop.

Sometimes you can use an exception to check if a string contains a value or if a file exists.

You can use exceptions to terminate threads collaboratively.

You should also consider that different languages have different conventions about when exceptions should be thrown (e.g. Python > C++ > Objective C).

Objective C is [an extreme](http://exceptions%20are%20used%20solely%20for%20programmer%20errors):

> When you’re writing code with Objective-C, exceptions are used solely for programmer errors

*(iOS Developer Library - Dealing with Errors)*

but this isn't the norm.

Comment: Please don't answer offtopic questions here; rather vote or flag for migration and answer on the proper site.

Answer (score 0):

An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions.

[check here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)